# Redis counter consistently being off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

This is a long question, so apologies in advance. We're using Redis to track customer states for each company. The customer states are tracked because we have customers separated by states in tabs on our website.

Whenever a customer instance is saved (after_save), we look to see what has changed and increment/decrement the relevant counts. For some reason, the counts are off pretty frequently and we can't figure out why. We wrote tests and verified all logic looks correct.

One thing to note is that we use sidekiq for background processing quite often, not sure if that will affect it or not.

We have 3 counts that we're calculating: my_customers_length (customers that have a user_id, which means they are 'assigned' to that user), all_customers_length (customers that are either 'open' or 'assigned', open means aasm_state = 'open' and they don't have a user_id), and open_customers_length (customers that aasm_state = 'open' and don't have a user_id).

Here's the logic that increments/decrements the Redis counters (after_save in customer.rb):

```
  def reset_stats
    if user_id_changed?
      if user_id_was == nil # open => assigned
        # update company and user
        user.redis_increment_my_customers_length
        company.redis_decrement_open_customers_length
      elsif user_id_was != nil && user_id != nil # assigned => assigned
        # update users (assigner and assignee)
        user_was = User.find(user_id_was)
        user.redis_increment_my_customers_length
        user_was.redis_decrement_my_customers_length
      elsif user_id_was != nil && user_id == nil # assigned => closed
        # update company and user
        user_was = User.find(user_id_was)
        user_was.redis_decrement_my_customers_length
        company.redis_decrement_all_customers_length
      end
    else
      if aasm_state_was == 'closed' && aasm_state == 'open' # closed => open
        # update company
        company.redis_increment_all_customers_length
        company.redis_increment_open_customers_length
      elsif aasm_state_was == 'open' && aasm_state == 'closed' # open => closed
        # update company
        company.redis_decrement_all_customers_length
        company.redis_decrement_open_customers_length
      end
    end
  end
```

and here are the redis functions:

user.rb:

```
  def redis_length_key
    "my_customers_length_for_#{id}"
  end

  def set_my_customers_length(l)
    RED.set(redis_length_key, l)
    l
  end

  def redis_increment_my_customers_length
    set_my_customers_length(my_customers_length.to_i + 1)
  end

  def redis_decrement_my_customers_length
    set_my_customers_length(my_customers_length.to_i - 1)
  end
```

and company.rb:

```
  def open_customers
    customers.open
  end

  def redis_open_length_key
    "open_customers_length_for_#{id}"
  end

  def set_open_customers_length(l)
    RED.set(redis_open_length_key, l)
    l
  end

  def redis_increment_open_customers_length
    set_open_customers_length(open_customers_length.to_i + 1)
  end

  def redis_decrement_open_customers_length
    set_open_customers_length(open_customers_length.to_i - 1)
  end

  def open_customers_length(reset = false)
    l = RED.get(redis_open_length_key)
    if l.present? && reset == false && l.to_i >=0
      l
    else
      set_open_customers_length(open_customers.length)
    end
  end

  def redis_all_length_key
    "all_customers_length_for_#{id}"
  end

  def set_all_customers_length(l)
    RED.set(redis_all_length_key, l)
    l
  end

  def all_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_all_length_key)
  end

  def redis_increment_all_customers_length
    set_all_customers_length(all_customers_length.to_i + 1)
  end

  def redis_decrement_all_customers_length
    set_all_customers_length(open_or_claimed_customers_length.to_i - 1)
  end

  def open_or_claimed_customers_length(reset = false)
    l = RED.get(redis_all_length_key)
    if l.present? && reset == false && l.to_i >=0
      l
    else
      set_all_customers_length(open_or_claimed_customers.length)
    end
  end

  def open_or_claimed_customers
    customers.open_or_claimed
  end
```

We noticed that the "open" customers count in Redis is always less than the actual count by hitting the database. For "my customers count" and "all customers count," Redis is usually lower but not always.

Is our logic wrong? Are we missing something? Could this be a Redis problem? Sidekiq problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your Redis logic is not atomic, it's got a giant race condition in `redis_increment_open_customers_length`.  Use the `INCR` command instead of `GET` + `SET`.

http://redis.io/commands/incr